# Why are 2 numeric values with many decimal places considered equal in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Why is `select (1.9999999999999999+2)/2 = (1.9999999999999999999999999999999999+2)/2` equal to `true` in postgres? Doing `select pg_typeof((1.9999999999999999999999999999999999+2)/2)` shows type `numeric`, which the docs say are exact numbers are should support thousands of digits after the decimal.

`select 1.9999999999999999 = 1.9999999999999999999999999999999999` returns `false` as expected.

Why does select `(1.999999999999999+2)/2` show `1.9999999999999995` like I'd expect but adding an extra "9" to the end shows `2.0000000000000000`? Shouldn't the extra digit increase the precision and I should see the extra "9" in the result too?

In what cases can I be sure I won't see this in my queries when doing arithmetic on `numeric` types?

Comment: Decimal numbers represented as floating point  are NEVER exact in binary computers at some number of digits they are all estimates.

Comment: @Belayer Read the postgres docs. The `numeric` type is meant to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

The numeric expression on the left side has only 16 decimal digits.  The overall expression evaluation is limited to that precision.

Try this:

```
select (1.9999999999999999000000000000000000+2)/2 = (1.9999999999999999999999999999999999+2)/2
```

And you'll get false because you are now comparing 34 decimals on both sides (if I counted right).

Comment: Why does `select (1.999999999999999+2)/2` show `1.9999999999999995` like I'd expect but adding an extra "9" to the end shows `2.0000000000000000`? Shouldn't the extra digit increase the precision and I should see the extra "9" in the result too?

Comment: I seem to recall the numeric value scale/precision is allocated in chunks so there probably is space to do the division in the former case but not the latter case.  The division is adding a decimal.  I'm sure others with more knowledge of internals will be able to explain this all in detail.  I shall be watching for them too :-)